# Isn't a const variable at namespace scope implicitly static?

Tags: c++

I know that `static const int x = 42;` at namespace scope is equivalent to `const int x = 42;` because `const` variables are implicitly `static` (they must be declared `extern` to be given external linkage).  Every translation unit that includes this declaration gets a local copy of `x`.

Does this only apply to certain (perhaps integer?) types?  I have the following code in a header file:

```
namespace XXX {
    static const char* A = "A";
    static const char* B = "B";
    static const char* C = "C"; // and so on
}
```

**(PLEASE spare me the comments on why I should not be using C-style strings -- this is legacy code)**

This header is included from several source files, and all is fine (each compilation unit gets its own copy of these `char*`'s).  I would have thought that I could remove the `static` from these, as it is redundant, but when I do, I get link errors about the symbols being already defined in another object.  What am I missing here?  Are these `const char*`'s **not** implicitly static?

Comment: C strings are evil. They will make your teeth rot, your skin wrinkle, and steal candy from babies. Shame on you for ever thinking that you could use them in legacy code. You must spend several years rewriting your project with purely C++ strings. :-)

Comment: Actually, creating named constants for string values is a good use of char * strings. If you use std::string, then a string instance will be created, using dynamic memory allocation, in each translation unit that #includes the string definitions. This is wasteful, and in the event of a memory allocation problem, hard to diagnose.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your example, you are creating a pointer to a constant (block of) char rather than creating a constant pointer to a char. Thus, your pointer isn't constant and so isn't implicitly static.

You need to declare `x` as `const char *const A`, which creates a constant pointer to a constant (block of) char.

Comment: Yes. That'll create a constant pointer to a block of constant chars, which is what you'd want for a string literal.